# distributed logging: JMS and log4j?

Tags: log4j, jms

Been doing some searching for a solution to this problem: I need log entries from apps running on several machines to be sent to & aggregated on a remote server. Requirements:

1. logging in the app needs to be asynchronous (can't wait for log entry to traverse network)
2. logging in the app needs to be queued; if the network fails, log entries need to be queued locally and sent to
   centralized server when the network becomes available again

I'm looking at using log4j and a JMSAppender. Assuming that's a suitable solution, are there any examples available? What process would be running on the centralized server to receive log entries in this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One simple setup I came to think about is to use [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)

It is an open source messaging broker (JMS compatible) that is able to cluster queues among several physical machines and the ActiveMQ installation is rather lightweight. You simple install one ActiveMQ on each of your applications machines. Then on the logging server (Physical Server C in the picture) you would have another ActiveMQ. Your application would use a JMS appender ([read more here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html)) and you could actually just use the included [apache camel](http://camel.apache.org) to read from the queue and write a log on file or database without needing to write an application for that task.

It could be as simple as adding something like the following to the camel.xml in the activemq /conf installation and import the camel.xml in the activemq.xml configuration.

```
<route>
 <from uri="activemq:queue:LogQueue"/>
 <to uri="file:target/folder/?fileName=logfile.log&fileExist=Append"/>
</route>
```

[image: Distributed Logging Example]

You could use a myrriad of other frameworks, JMS servers and technologies, but I think this is a rather easy approach to achieve with very low cost and high stability.